# Компиляция классов maven

Tags: maven, классы, компиляция

Доброго времени суток! Погуглила и ничего, а проблема то вот в чем: есть мавенский веб проект, при компиляции необходимо исключить 2 класса. Каким образом это возможно?

Comment: а если полностью пакет исключить , то как?

Comment: > а если полностью пакет исключить , то как?

каждый джава пакет имеет свою отдельную папочку, `java.util.Date` в файловой структуре будет выглядеть так: `<source folder>/java/util/Date.java`

поэтому пакет исключить можно так: `<source folder>/java/util/*` (пустая папка должна быть проигнорирована) или так: `<source folder>/java/util`

Answer (score 1):

Например, так:

```
<project>
  ....
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>SomeClass.java</exclude>
        </excludes> 
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins> 
  ....
</project>
```

Comment: я попробовала, не прошел такой трюк

Comment: попробуйте так: `**/SomeClass.java`

Comment: @Ольга, jmu дело говорит. Мой пример непосредственно для случая, когда `SomeClass.java` лежит непосредственно в директории исходников.